# shell script: can't cd to

Tags: php, shell

i need an help, i want to make a webpage that allow to start/stop/restart a program on the server where there is the website.

my html:

```html
    <tr>
  <td>JTS</td>
  <td>
   <form action="JTSstart.php">
   <input type="submit" value="START">
   </form>
  </td>
    <td>
   <form action="JTSres.php">
   <input type="submit" value="RESTART">
   </form>
  </td>
    <td>
   <form action="JTSstop.php">
   <input type="submit" value="STOP">
   </form>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

my php:

```html
<?php
echo shell_exec('sh JTSres.sh');
sleep(5);
header("Location: 5ondimba.html");
?>
```

and my sh:

```html
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/home/otaku/JTS_HostingEdition
./jts_startscript.sh restart
```

now.. when i click on one of all button's nothing happens and on the error.log in /var/log/apache2, it say:

```
JTSres.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to /home/otaku/JTS_HostingEdition
```

i try to search something on stackoverflow but nothing can help me.
what i can try to do?
thanks for all!

Comment: Chances are your webserver doesn't have permission to that folder.

Comment: you don't need cd, just use the 'whole' path in the script

Comment: @nogad If he doesn't have permission to `cd` to the directory, he won't be able to run scripts from it either.

Comment: oh i agree, @Barmar, but its still a smarter way to do *once* you fix the permission issue

Comment: @ceejayoz, this file and the folder have 0777.

Comment: @nogad you mean "/home/otaku/JTS_HostingEdition/jts_startscript.sh restart"??

Comment: @Flynns82 : (1) You have a bash script, but you run it explicitly as sh script. (2) Are you sure that you have a directory _home_ which is **below** your home directory? The `~/home/....` looks weird to me. (3) Whatever happened, this tilde was replaced by the nullstring. I suggest that within your bash script, you output the user id under which the script is running, and also do a `set -x` for turning on tracing.

Comment: @user1934428 i have correct the case of bash/sh script, for the directory i have only 1 "home" dir, on the root there is only one home

Comment: @user1934428 by using the tracing i see this: JTSstop.sh: riga 4: cd: $'/home/otaku/JTS_HostingEdition/\r': File o directory non esistente

Comment: Get rid of the \r! You don't have Unix line endings in your script.

Comment: @user1934428, on the script i never write \r, idk what it is

Comment: @user1934428 UPDATE: i solve it by converting sh script with dos2unix, now if i run sh script from console works, but when i try to start it from website nothing happens, but on the error.log(apache2) there are nothing..

Comment: To see, what the script is doing, I would run it again with `-x` enabled. Since you do a `echo shell_exec(....)` on your website, you should see at least *something*. Also, I definitely would run the script using `bash`, not `sh`. I don't quite understand why you are using `sh` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the permissions on all the directories, and the script, so that the webserver can access them.

```
chmod a+rx /home/otaku /home/otaku/JTS_HostingEdition /home/otaku/JTS_HostingEdition/jts_startscript
```

BTW, using `~` in a script that can be run by different users doesn't make much sense, since that expands to the user's own home directory. You should use the absolute path of the directory you want to change to. It seems like this is only finding the correct path because the webserver's home directory is the root directory, so `~/home` is the same as `/home`.

Also, if the `JTSres.sh` is a `bash` script, you should run it with `bash`, not `sh`.

```
echo shell_exec('bash JTSres.sh');
```

Or make the script executable and use:

```
echo shell_exec("./JTSres.sh");
```

Comment: after i had change bash in sh now on the log there is:
sh: 1: ./JTSstop.sh: Permission denied
and after i give the permissions a+rx there is:
sh: 1: ./JTSstop.sh: not found

Comment: What is `JTSstop.sh`?

Comment: ah, sorry, ehm its the same of JTSres, (1 to restart, 1 to stop...) now im trying to stop the program with all this

Comment: If you changed `sh` to `bash` I don't know why the error message says `sh`.

Comment: i changed to sh. now the php is: echo shell_exec("./JTSstop.sh");

and the sh file is with #!/bin/sh

Comment: The file should be `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: ah ok! anyway i type #!/bin/bash but it say again "sh: 1: ./JTSstop.sh: not found"

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with the filename, or it's not in the same directory as the PHP script.

Comment: all the files are on the same directory and the name its the same, this error appear when i change shell_exec('sh JTSres.sh'); to ./JTSres.sh
   can php need a different syntax?

Comment: i try to put 'sh JTSstop.sh' instead of ./JTSstop.sh and now "work"(now the error is "JTSstop.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to..."

Comment: UPDATE: i try to put into php file this: " echo shell_exec('sh /home/otaku/JTS3ServerMod_HostingEdition/jts3servermod_startscript.sh stop'); " and now on the error log of apache2 there is no error, but anyway nothing happens..